# Insert HTML code in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, userscripts

I m new to scripting, and I started with Javascript. I m creating a script that takes value from a drop down list and process the input with the chosen value. Since HTML is not accepted in javascript files (.js) , I tried inserting the HTML select list as a script ,so that it may work. But that doesn't seem working. I have included my code below. Need some help in inserting a HTML code in Javascript. Thanks in advance.

My Code:

```
window.onload = function() { 

  var p = document.createElement("div")
  p.innerHTML = 'Script to calculate the eligibility of a u20 player ' +
    '<div style="padding-left:0em;"><b>U20  ELIGIBILITY  CALCULATOR</b></div>'+ 'Years : ' +
    '<div style=" display: inline-block; float: center; text-align: center;">' +        
      '<select id="x">'+
        '<option value="17">17 yrs</option>' +
        '<option value="18">18 yrs</option>' +
        '<option value="19">19 yrs</option>' +
        '<option value="20">20 yrs</option>' +
      '</select>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<input type = "button" id = "calc" value = "Calculate Age" onclick = "calc_age()"/>' + 'He will be'+
    '<input type = "text" id = "w" size="1" readonly />';
}

function calc_age()  // to find age at the registration deadline
{
  var n1,n2;
  n1=document.getElementById("x").value;
  n2=n1*2; // i have changed the operations here
  document.getElementById("w").value=n2;
}
```

Comment: I don't Understand your question...

Comment: Syntax Check your code --- You're missing a div.

Comment: Separate `JavaScript` with `HTML`, have a look at my answer

Comment: Also, append the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the element `p`, you'll have to append it somewhere in the document.  But first, instead of innerHTML, I would create the elements and append them to p, like so:

```js
var p = document.createElement("div");
    p.appendChild( document.createTextNode("Script to calculate the eligibility of a u20 player ") );

var el = document.createElement("div");
    el.id = "jefree";
    el.style.float = "center";
    p.appendChild(el);
// Study that for a second, creating any other element (even with nested elements) is the same way

var listEl = document.createElement("select");
    listEl.id = "x";
    for( var x = 17; x < 21; x++ ){
        var optionEl = document.createElement("option");
            optionEl.value = x;
            optionEl.appendChild( document.createTextNode(x) );
            listEl.appendChild(optionEl);
    }
    p.appendChild(listEl);

document.body.appendChild(p);
```

Also, the way to get a select-box's value is to get the selected index, then find that value.

```
var list = document.getElementById("x");
    list.options[ list.selectedIndex ].value;
```

Comment: @JefreeSujit Sure, it's the same concept.  Create an element, change its attributes, then append it to whatever parent you'd like it to belong to.

Comment: could you please do the same for the list i provided, in your above sample code..?

Comment: sorry to say, i tried what you said... but it didnt work.. :(

Comment: yes, it works fine when i run the snippet here.. but it shows problem while running the same script in a website.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81566/discussion-between-jefree-sujit-and-gary).

Answer (score 0):

You could append the whole string to the body

```js
var p = '<div>Script to calculate the eligibility of a u20 player </div>';

document.body.innerHTML+=p;
document.body.innerHTML+='<div id="jefree" style="float: center;">'+
    '<div style="padding-left:0em;"><b>U20  ELIGIBILITY  CALCULATOR</b></div>'+ 'Years : ' +
    '<div style=" display: inline-block; float: center; text-align: center;">' +        
      '<select id="x">'+
        '<option value="17">17 yrs</option>' +
        '<option value="18">18 yrs</option>' +
        '<option value="19">19 yrs</option>' +
        '<option value="20">20 yrs</option>' +
      '</select>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<input type = "button" id = "calc" value = "Calculate Age" onclick = "calc_age()"/>' + 'He will be'+
    '<input type = "text" id = "w" size="1" readonly />';
function calc_age()  // to find age at the registration deadline
{
  var n1,n2;
  n1=document.getElementById("x").value;
  n2=n1*2; // i have changed the operations here
  document.getElementById("w").value=n2;
}
```

Comment: did you run the code snippet, it works, do you get a console error?

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. You failed to close all the divs. Look at how I reformatted your question.
2. You didn't append the element to the document. Use `parent.appendChild(element)` where element is the variable of type DOmElement that you want to insert and parent is where you want to insert it.

Also, do not put spaces between the equal sign, the attribute, and its value.

Comment: document.appendChild(p);

Answer (score -1):

As I said in the comment, try separating them.

Put the script code inside the `head` tag:

```
    <script>
        function calc_age(selectedValue)  // to find age at the registration deadline
        {
            selectedValue = parseInt(selectedValue.value);
            lastValue = selectedValue * 2;
            document.getElementById("w").value = lastValue;
        }
    </script>
```

And the HTML inside the `body` tag:

```
    <div>
        Script to calculate the eligibility of a u20 player
        <div id="jefree" style="float: center;">
            <div style="padding-left:0em;"><b>U20  ELIGIBILITY  CALCULATOR</b></div>
            Years :
            <div style=" display: inline-block; float: center; text-align: center;">
                <select id="x" onchange="calc_age(this);">
                <option value="17">17 yrs</option>
                <option value="18">18 yrs</option>
                <option value="19">19 yrs</option>
                <option value="20">20 yrs</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <input type = "button" id = "calc" value = "Calculate Age" onclick = "calc_age()"/>

            He will be <input type = "text" id = "w" size="1" readonly />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but am not writing a html code.. i want both the functions as well as the list in within the javascript file